# performance for a SQL clause with where and a left join

Tags: sql, left-join, where-clause, database-performance

Let say I have 2 tables, TblA et TblB.  TblA has millions of records each month while TblB has detailled informations for products.

Which query will be faster :

```
select
    t1.*, t2.name
from 
    TblA as t1
left join 
    TblB as T2 on t1.idProduct = t2.idProduct
where 
    t1.month = 6
```

Or this one :

```
select 
    t1.*, t2.name
from 
    (select * from tblA where month = 6) as t1
left join 
    TblB as t2 on t1.idProduct = t2.idProduct
```

My guess is the second one will be faster because I pre-select only the month I want before doing the left join.

Are database system pre-build to handle the where clause before doing the left join?

Thanks!

Comment: Run them and find out?

Comment: Why don't you run them each a few times and find out which is faster?

Comment: We only have a single month in the table so far.

Comment: One might suddenly run faster than the other when you have more months in the table. Or they might always run identically because the query planner recognises that they are the same thing. Take a look and understand the query plan.

Comment: You should at least tag your DBMS you are using (sql-server, oracle, mysql, etc). Also almost all rdbms systems have query plans. Use the query plan to compare not only the queries but also how the server chooses to execute them. Based on that you can refine the query as well as create index objects that might be necessary for efficiency.

Comment: Check the execution plans - but I doubt there will be any difference at all for any modern DBMS.

Comment: *If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then **race your horses*** - see [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by Eric Lippert for more background

Answer (score 0):

run them both and look at the query plans
it will even give you a split on estimated time

Answer (score 0):

It depends somewhat on which RDBMS you're using. However, most of them will interpret both of those queries as exactly the same. You can determine if that's true in your database by running an `explain plan` on both queries. If the plan is the same, then the optimizer has correctly identified that both queries are equivalent and come up with the same plan for both.

In general, SQL doesn't specify an order of operations; it lets the optimizer consider all of the options and choose the best one. Nesting the queries doesn't typically change that - almost any optimizer will flatten the query you give it as much as possible.